# How do I set a matplotlib colorbar extents?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to display a colorbar representing an image's raw values along side a matplotlib imshow subplot which displays that image, normalized.

I've been able to draw the image and a colorbar successfully like this, but the colorbar min and max values represent the normalized (0,1) image instead of the raw (0,99) image.

```
f = plt.figure()
# create toy image
im = np.ones((100,100))
for x in range(100):
    im[x] = x
# create imshow subplot
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
result = ax.imshow(im / im.max())

# Create the colorbar
axc, kw = matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes(ax)
cb = matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar(axc, result)

# Set the colorbar
result.colorbar = cb
```

If someone has a better mastery of the colorbar API, I'd love to hear from you.

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you passed the wrong object to the colorbar constructor.

This should work:

```
# make namespace explicit
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

cbar = fig.colorbar(result)
```

The snippet above is based on the code in your answer; here's a complete, stand-alone example:

```
import numpy as NP
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

A = NP.random.random_integers(0, 10, 100).reshape(10, 10)
fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

cax = ax1.imshow(A, interpolation="nearest")

# set the tickmarks *if* you want cutom (ie, arbitrary) tick labels:
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[0, 5, 10])

# note: 'ax' is not the same as the 'axis' instance created by calling 'add_subplot'
# the latter instance i bound to the variable 'ax1' to avoid confusing the two
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["lo", "med", "hi"])

PLT.show()
```

As i suggested in the comment above, i would choose a *cleaner namespace* that what you have--e.g., there are modules with the same name in both NumPy and Matplotlib.

In particular, i would use this import statement to import Matplotlib's "core" plotting functionality:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT
```

Of course, this does not get the entire matplotlib namespace (which is really the point of this import statement) though this is usually all that you'll need.

Comment: Out of interest @doug, why do you capitalise PLT and NP?

Comment: @bdforbes: so i just like namespaces that are clean (no overlap w/ another) plus i just like to have a quick visual way to identify them in my code--here of course, both PLT and NP are local variables bound to a library/module which subsumes other modules.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it might be too late, but...
For me replacing in the last line of Adam's code `result` by `ax` works out.